# An isomorphism on space of smooth sections

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, differential-topology, line-bundles

Let $M$ be a smooth complex manifold and $L$ be a complex line bundle over $M$. Let $\Gamma(M,L)$ be the space of smooth sections. Why $\Gamma(M,L)$ is it isomorphic to 
$$A=\{f:L^{\times}\to \mathbb{C}; f(cz)=c^{-1}f(z), c\in \mathbb{C}-\{0\} , z\in L^{\times}\}.$$
Here $L^{\times}$ is the structure bundle obtained from $L$ by removing the zero section.

Comment: A tiny remark. It's not a good idea call $L^\times$ a line bundle.

Comment: Thanks Anton, which word is suitable for $L^×$?

Comment: I'd say a bundle or a $\mathbb{C}^*$-bundle.

Comment: I think you can forget the complex structure, this construction applies to real symplectic manifolds. The fact that the fiber of the fiber bundle $L$ is the complex line $\bf C$ is accessory.

Comment: Yes, your right,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I want first to fix a confusion at the level of the two bundles involved in this construction. My way(*) is to consider, first of all, a $S^1$-bundle over a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, with curvature $\omega$ — assuming the symplectic form is integral. Let $(Y,\lambda)$ be this prequantization, and $\pi : y \mapsto x$ be the projection. Now, $S^1$, identified to the complex numbers of norm $1$, acts by multiplication on the field of complex numbers ${\bf C}$. You can then build a line bundle $p : L \to X$ as the associated bundle to $Y$ 
$$
 L = Y \times_{S^1} {\bf C} = [Y \times {\bf C}]/S^1,
$$
where $S^1$ acts diagonaly by $\underline z(y,Z)= (z_Y(y),zZ)$, $z \in S^1$, $y \in Y$, $Z \in {\bf C}$, and we have denoted by $\underline z : y \to z_Y(y)$ the action of $S^1$ on $Y$. Therefore $L$ is the space of classes $[y,Z]$ with $[y,Z] = [z_Y(y),zZ]$.

1. The subspace $Y \times S^1 \subset Y \times {\bf C}$ is stable under the action of $S^1$, thus it defines a sub-bundle in $L$ which is equivalent to $Y$ by $y \mapsto [y,1]$. This map is surjective since every $[y,z]$ with $z\in S^1$ writes $[y/z,1]$, and obviously injective. This is what, in this approach, replaces your bundle $L^\times$. And you can forget about it for now.
2. Next, consider an equivariant map $\Psi : Y \to {\bf C}$, that is, $\Psi(z_Y(y)) = z\Psi(y)$, that gives a map on the quotient $\psi :y \mapsto [y,\Psi(y)]$ satisfying 
   $$
   \psi(z_Y(y)) = [z_Y(y),\Psi(z_Y(y))]=[z_Y(y),z\Psi(y)]=[y,\Psi(y)] = \psi(y).
   $$
   Thus, $\psi$ is invariant by the action of $S^1$, then there exists a function (smooth because the projections involved are submersions) $\varphi : X \to L$ such that $\varphi(x) = [y,\Psi(y)]$ for any $y$ such that $\pi(y)=x$. And by construction, $\varphi$ is a section of $L$. You can show now that conversely, any section $\varphi$ of $\pi : Y \to M$ gives you an equivariant map $\Psi$. Take the pullback by the projection $(y,Z) \mapsto [y,Z]$ of the image of the section $\varphi$.

(*) That is the Souriau's construction.

Comment: The symplectic structure appears to play no role at all in this.

Comment: @FranBurstall Sure, but I know also that our friend Hassan is working on geometric quantization (previous exchanges) I just anticipate his needs. And, as you mentioned in your reply, $S^1$ can be replaced by any group $G$, and the associated bundle built with any action of $G$ on a space $E$, the construction will be identical. We agree :-)

Comment: @PatrickI-Z: very nice explanation. Do you have a reference for this? In particular that explains how a connection on the principal $U(1)$-bundle explicitly induces a connection on the associated line bundle $L$.

Comment: @Bilateral I would say that the Kobayashi-Nomizu "Foundations of Differential Geometry " could be a good general reference.

Comment: @PatrickI-Z: thanks. A general question: the associated complex, rank-1, vector bundle to a $U(1)$-bundle is not necessarily an holomorphic line bundle, right?

Comment: @Bilateral What are your hypothesis?

Comment: @PatrickI-Z: suppose that $P$ is a principal $U(1)$ bundle over a complex manifold $M$. Then, the vector bundle associated to $P$ is not necessarily an holomorphic line bundle, right? In general it should be a rank-1 complex vector bundle, not necessarily holomorphic. By the way, if you have a minute I am sure you can confirm what I suspect here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1231181/correspondence-between-line-bundles-and-u1-bundles-a-mistake-from-the-physi

Comment: @Bilateral First question, yes, there is no reason the fiber bundle has a holomorphic atlas. You need another condition. But it is clearly documented in
 http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/holomorphic+vector+bundle For the second question, I have no time now. I'll look when i'll be back from Paris, in a few days.

Answer (score 4):

Given $f\in A$, observe that $z\mapsto f(z)z$ is constant on fibres of $L^\times$ and so gives a well-defined element of $\Gamma(M,L)$.  That is the isomorphism.

What is really going on here is the standard isomorphism between sections of a vector bundle and equivariant vector-valued functions on its frame bundle.  In your case, $L^\times$ is the frame bundle of $L$.

Answer (score 1):

Locally a section is just a smooth function $s:U\to\mathbb{C}$. Given such a function, define $f(x, t) = \frac{s(x)}{t}$. Here $x$ stands for a point on $M$ and $t$ is a local coordinate in the fiber. Conversely, given such an $f$, define $s(x)$ to be the unique solution of the equation $f(x, s(x))=1$ (if doesn't exist, put $s(x)=0$).

Now observe that this construction behaves nicely under gluing.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing the line bundle $L$ and its dual $L^*$. A section $s\in \Gamma (M,L)$ provides a linear map $L^*\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, by $(m,\xi) \mapsto \langle s(m ),\xi \rangle$ for $m\in M$, $\xi \in L_m^*$.  Conversely,  a linear map $\ell:L^*\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ 
defines for each $m\in M$ a linear form $\ell_m:L^*_m\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$, hence a unique $s(m)\in L_m$.

Comment: abx , your solution is not correct

Comment: Funny, if there is a "right" answer to the question, it is yours.